# ActiveMQ Browser setup for ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying install ActiveMQ Browser, and I wanted to connect with my ActiveMQ Artemis server. How do we configure that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/activemqbrowser/) ActiveMQ Browser GUI tool.

If that assumption is correct then there's no way to integrate it with ActiveMQ Artemis as it's hard-coded to use the specific JMX management beans from ActiveMQ 5.x.

I recommend you use the ActiveMQ Artemis web console. It has a rich set of functionality that should cover most of the use-cases you're interested in. Among other things, it will allow you to:

- Send new messages to addresses.
- Delete messages.
- Move messages to another address.
- Create or delete addresses & queues.
- Shutdown broker.
- etc.